# Git pull keeps the files from the wordpress upload folder?

Tags: wordpress, git, deployment, github, git-pull

I installed Wordpress on my server and am testing modes to automatically deploy.

The question is: When a git pull, the files in the folder uploads will be kept on the server?

Comment: Git pull just integrates all changes done on the remote side into your local repository resp. your active checked out branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is: When a git pull, the files in the folder uploads will be kept on the server?

It seems the `/uploads/` folder is not under version control so yes it will be kept on the server.

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/tree/master/wp-content